# How to Load rdlc report runtime

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

i created 2  reports billa4.rdlc and billa5.rdlc and i want to load one of the report to the reportviewer as per the selection of option of combobox by user .
please help me for this .
the below code is loading the  billa4.rdlc

```
Try
        Dim P2 As New ReportParameter("pbillnum", billnoprint)
        Me.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.billdata.DataTable1, billnoprint)
        Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {P2})
        Me.ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
        Me.ReportViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FullPage
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("error")
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? Don't set up an report source directly from the design mode, do it by code.

Maybe something like this:

```
if( combooption.SelectedValue = 0) Then
        Dim P2 As New ReportParameter("pbillnum", billnoprint)
        Me.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.billdata.DataTable1, billnoprint)
        Me.ReportViewer1.ViewReport("billa4.rdlc")
        Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {P2})
        Me.ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
        Me.ReportViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FullPage
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
else
        Dim P2 As New ReportParameter("pbillnum", billnoprint)
        Me.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.billdata.DataTable1, billnoprint)
        Me.ReportViewer1.ViewReport("billa5.rdlc")
        Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {P2})
        Me.ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
        Me.ReportViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FullPage
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End if
```

Comment: Dim P2 As New ReportParameter("pbillnum", billnoprint)
        Me.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.billdata.DataTable1, billnoprint)
        Me.ReportViewer2.LocalReport.ReportPath("Bill.rdlc")

        Me.ReportViewer2.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {P2})
        Me.ReportViewer2.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
        Me.ReportViewer2.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FullPage
        Me.ReportViewer2.RefreshReport()
i tried thi but not working